# C# How to get automated number of heading in Word Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have code (as soon below) that loops through all the paragraphs and finds a specific string. When I find the string, I print out the automated number of the header it belongs to. The problem, I want the header number as well and can't figure out how to get it. Code here:

Edit: Cleaned up code with working content

```
string LastHeader = "";

foreach (Paragraph paragraph in aDoc.Paragraphs)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style thisStyle = 
           (paragraph.Range.get_Style() as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style);
    if (thisStyle != null && thisStyle.NameLocal.StartsWith("Heading 2"))
    {
        LastHeader = paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListString + " " + 
                        paragraph.Range.Text.Replace("\"", "\"\"").Replace("\r", "");
    }
    else
    { 
        string content = paragraph.Range.Text;

        for (int i = 0; i < textToSearch.Count; i++)
        {
            if (content.Contains(textToSearch[i]))
            {
                // Do stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A "Section" is a specific object in Word and it has an Index property, so your use of the term is misleading. Would I be correct in assuming that 1) Heading styles have been applied to these "sections" AND 2) Word's automatic numbering has been used to generate the numbers AND 3) you want the nearest preceding heading level information? If the boolean answer to all three is NOT true, then is the textToAnalyse Word.Range object THAT paragraph with the numbering AND is it automatic numbering?

Comment: @CindyMeister Yes that is correct. We call them "sections" when talking about them, I realize now I am conflicting with an actual word term. I want the automated numbering that is before the heading text. The textToAnalyse does NOT appear to contain the numbering, just the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time I re-read your information I get the feeling I'm not understanding completely what you're asking, so the following may contain more information than you're looking for...

To get the numbering of a specific Paragraph:

```
paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListString
```

Word has some built-in bookmarks that can give you information that is otherwise a lot of work to determine. One of these is \HeadingLevel. This gets the first paragraph formatted with a Heading style that precedes a SELECTION. And that's the sticky part, because we don't really want to be making selections... But it dates back to the old WordBasic days when code mimicked user actions, so we're stuck with that.

```
textToAnalyse.Select
aDoc.Bookmarks("\HeadingLevel").Range.ListFormat.ListString
```

The bookmark call, itself, will NOT change the selection.

The other option I see, since you're already looping the Paragraphs collection, would be to check the paragraph.Range.Style and, if it begins with the string "Heading" (assuming that's not used otherwise in these documents' styles) save the `ListFormat.ListString` so that you can call on it if your condition is met.

I do have to wonder, however, why you're "walking" the paragraphs collection and not using Word's built-in Find capability as that would be much faster. It can search text AND (style) formatting.

Comment: I want to be able to find the heading ("1.2.3 Some Title") and get that entire line back. However the code I posted only gives me ("Some Title"). I need the missing 1.2.3. I tried using the search, however I could not find a way to backtrack and determine the paragraph it belonged to. The Paragraphs member was empty on the search Selection

Comment: paragraph.Range.ListFormat.ListString was what I needed. Thank you